# parsing aws cloudfront log

Tags: parsing, amazon-cloudfront, logfiles

I have a shell script which parses the aws cloudfront log.

```
awk '{print $1","$2","$4","$5","$8","$9","(substr($11,1,7))","$12 }' access_log | grep cid= | sed -e 's/\/data//g;s/\/videos//g;s/\/images//g;s/\/hls//g;s/\/rss//g;s/\/xml//g;s/cid=//g' > stats.txt
```

I am trying to combine fields $1 and $2 so the date time stamp resembles this format:
   Date_time
   0000-00-00 00:00:00

It is currently in two fields date, time
   2012-12-23  20:59:47

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The awk portion of your script is adding a comma between the date and time portions of what you want to be formatted as datetime.  This is causing "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" to appear as "YYYY-MM-DD,HH:MM:SS".

To get the result you're after change your script to:

```
awk '{print $1" "$2","$4","$5","$8","$9","(substr($11,1,7))","$12 }' access_log | grep cid= | sed -e 's/\/data//g;s/\/videos//g;s/\/images//g;s/\/hls//g;s/\/rss//g;s/\/xml//g;s/cid=//g' > stats.txt
```

This should insert into the datetime field correctly.